# SMD component on a dotmatrix printer driver board

Tags: surface-mount, repair, reverse-engineering

[image]

This SMD (code: 327G) is mostly used between data lines from the microprocessor and (possibly) some solenoids of a dot matrix printer. So it should be some switching device. I redraw related part of the circuit as below.

[image]

The ones that are used on data lines same way but the one which is used to drive DC motor slightly different. What could it be ?

Answer (score 1):

> What could it be ?

Sounds like a FET array.

Comment: Do you know the meaning of lines over the numbers ?

Comment: no idea, but you probably wouldn't want to buy the exact same thing, but simply an array that fits the same current and threshold voltage needs, which you could infer from knowing your motor and measuring your control voltages.